# How to remove this UI element at eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, editor

I don't know, what's name have this control, but I want hide it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the "Toggle Breadcrumb" icon on the toolbar..

hope it helps...

Comment: I don't find this icon. But by `Quick Access` I hide it. Thanks for name "breadcrumb".